# Javascript - cutting out part of a string

Tags: javascript, substring

**Hello everyone,**

I'm trying to find the best way to cut out specific parts of the below **input** string.
I'm using a white space (' ') as a separator. But I'm unable to cut out the required parts
 and assign them into respective variables.

```
var input = "/w user1 message"

var user = input.substring(2, input.indexOf(' '));?? 
var message = ???
```

expected result:

```
user = "user1"
message = "message"
```

It only works when the empty spaces are replaced with a coma or any other separator.

Is there any specific reason why iit's not working with spaces?

Thanks in advance,
Alex

Comment: And what part do you want to remove, what's the expected result ?

Comment: Anyway -> `input.substring(2, input.lastIndexOf(' '));`

Comment: Note that `/w` has no special meaning in strings, if you meant it to.

Comment: or `input.split(/\s+/)[1]`

Comment: I've update my post with the expected results. As @TJ Crowser pointed out , the "/w" has no special meaning in this case.

Comment: any ideas why `input.substr(2, input.indexOf(' '); ` does not return the "user1" part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using split, it creates an array and you can just access the array by index

http://jsfiddle.net/PJH28/

```
var input = "/w user1 message"

var inputParts = input.split(' ');
var message = inputParts[2];
console.log(message);
```

Comment: I think this would be the best and simplest way how to make it work.

Comment: Sounds good.  If this works out for you, please consider marking it as the selected answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just try with:

```
var message = input.substr(input.indexOf(' ', input.indexOf(' ') + 1) + 1);
```

Comment: @putvande Sorry, edited. I do not know why I forgot about substr ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this..

```
// set up
var commands = {
    '/w': ['user']
};

//later
var arr = input.split(' '), o = {}, i;
if (arr[0] in commands) {
    o.command = arr.shift();
    for (i = 0; i < commands[o.command].length; ++i) {
        o[commands[o.command][i]] = arr.shift();
    }
}
o.message = arr.join(' ');
o;
```

Testing with your `var input = "/w user1 foo bar baz";` gives me

```
Object {command: "/w", user: "user1", message: "foo bar baz"}
```

This should now be much easier to use with other things

Comment: To be fair, he's in complete control of the input string.  If he were to go the object route, he could just pass in a json string or javascript object.

Comment: @Smeegs really? It looked to me like a chatroom/IRC style thing

Comment: He said that when uses a comma delimited string it works.  It sounds like he has control over the input string.